# Positioning miltiple views programmatically in swift

Tags: swift, loops

With your last help my loop is functioning well. But only once. If I try to reload it I get the following mistake: "Index out of range" in the following line:

```
let cardOnTop = cards[index-8]
```

Could somebody help me?

Here is my code:

```
func layoutCards() {

        //  create cards array with several elements
        var cards = (1...64).map { _ in UIView() }// array with several cards


        //Loop through each card in the array
        for index in 0...cards.count-1 {



            // place the card in the view and turn off translateAutoresizingMask
            let thisCard = cards[index]

            thisCard.layer.borderWidth = 1
            thisCard.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
            thisCard.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

            thisCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            midView.addSubview(thisCard)

            //set the height and width constraints
            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: thisCard, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: midView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.125, constant: 0)
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: thisCard, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: midView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.125, constant: 0)
            midView.addConstraints([heightConstraint, widthConstraint])

            //set the horizontal  position

            if (columnCounter > 0) {

                // card is not in the first column
                let cardOnTheLeft = cards[index-1]

                let leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: thisCard, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cardOnTheLeft, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

                //add constraint to the contentView
                midView.addConstraint(leftSideConstraint)

            } else {

                //card is in the first column

                let leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: thisCard, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: midView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

                //add constraint to the contentView
                midView.addConstraint(leftSideConstraint)

            }


            //set the vertical position

            if (rowCounter > 0) {

                // card is not in the first row
                let cardOnTop = cards[index-8]

                let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: thisCard, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cardOnTop, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

                // add constraint to the contentView
                midView.addConstraint(topConstraint)

            } else {

                //card is in the first row

                let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: thisCard, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: midView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

                //add constraint to the contentView
                midView.addConstraint(topConstraint)

            }



            //increment the column counter
            columnCounter = columnCounter+1

            //if the column counter reaches the fifth column reset it and increase the row counter
            if (columnCounter >= 8) {
                columnCounter = 0
                rowCounter = rowCounter+1
            }




        } // end of the loop



    }
```

Comment: For any value of index less than 8, that line is attempting to access an index less than 0. The first call would be looking for cards[-8] which is clearly out of range. You need to change your code to protect against this.

Comment: if (rowCounter > 0 && index > 7) {...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say this is failing when you run it a second time.  That is because you apparently have `rowCounter` and `columnCounter` declared as properties and you are not setting `rowCounter` and `columnCounter` back to `0` each time `layoutCards()` is called.

Make `rowCounter` and `columnCounter` be local variables to `layoutCards()`:

```
func layoutCards() {
    var rowCounter = 0
    var columnCounter = 0

    //  create cards array with several elements
    var cards = (1...64).map { _ in UIView() }// array with several cards
```